# Android Studio, java, onActivityResult is not being triggered using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have two activities:

**Activity #1**: `SetListMasterViewActivity`

**Activity #2**: `SetListOpenViewActivity`

**Activity #1** initially calls **Activity #2** with `Intent` variables, and this works fine.  **Activity #1** contains a `List` of songs, when the user clicks on any song in the List, the song opens with all song lyrics in **Activity #2**.  By pressing back within **Activity #2** the user is again returned to the List in Activity #1 but this time the song previously viewed in **Activity #2** is now highlighted (in the List within Activity #1).

It is when the user clicks `"Back"`, from **Activity #2** - sending the processing back to **Activity #1** - that I have a problem.  The logic is that, in **Activity #2** the user is viewing the text of a song (song lyrics).  When the user clicks `"Back"` button, the processing goes back to **Activity #1** with the song that the user was viewing in **Activity #2** is now highlighted within the List.

In **Activity #2**, within `onCreate()`, here is the code for the `"Back"` where I set the Intent:

```
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentPosition = getCurrentPosition(songName, songsList);
                String currentSongName = songsList.get(currentPosition);
                int currentSongId = getSongIdByName(currentSongName);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("lastViewedSongId", currentSongId);
                resultIntent.putExtra("lastViewedSongName", currentSongName);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
                startSetListMasterViewActivity();
            }
        });
```

After `Intent` is started, processing then continues to this method:

```
    private void startSetListMasterViewActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SetListOpenViewActivity.this, SetListMasterViewActivity.class);
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListOpenViewActivity) line #194 - Launching SetListMasterViewActivity");
        setListMasterViewLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

Which invokes this method:

```
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> setListMasterViewLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                Log.d("SttList", "(SetListOpenViewActivity) line #208 - ActivityResultLauncher");
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
    );
```

Within **Activity #1**, this is where the `Intent` is received:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #191 - onActivityResult called");
        Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #192 - requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SET_LIST_MASTER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            // Retrieve the last viewed song information from the Intent
            int lastViewedSongId = data.getIntExtra("lastViewedSongId", -1);
            String lastViewedSongName = data.getStringExtra("lastViewedSongName");

            // Find the position of the last viewed song in list of song names
            int position = songNames.indexOf(lastViewedSongName);
            // Log the received data
            Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #201 - Received lastViewedSongId: " + lastViewedSongId);
            Log.d("SttList", "(SetListMasterViewActivity) line #202 - Received lastViewedSongName: " + lastViewedSongName);

            // Highlight the song
            if (position != -1) {
                // Highlight the song at the found position
                TextView songTextView = (TextView) songsListView.getChildAt(position);
                songTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens is that **Activity #1** opens however none of the Intents from **Activity #2** are received.  All the Log.d statements in `onActivityResult` are not run, so it seems that `onActivityResult` is skipped all together.

I have tried moving all code in `onActivityResult` into `onResume` - in **Activity #1** - but find that the `Intent` is not received within `onResume`.  I have looked at other problems posted but cannot find the issue I am facing.

***What else I have tried:***

- `setResult()` is what you need for it to call `onActivityResult()` -
  yes I am using `setResult()`
- In `setResult` I am using `setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);`
- originally I tried coding the Intent with `startActivityForResult`, which a lot of the older answers use, however this is depreciated with AS stating: `'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your flow of data between activities. The Activity Result API is for returning results to a previous activity, but you seem to be using to try to pass results to a new activity?

Comment: Thank you for your observation @ianhanniballake  - the parent activity (Activity #1) passes data to the child activity (Activity #2), and then the child activity passes data back to the parent activity.  I am not starting a new activity - there's no need to start a new activity; instead, I'm simply returning data to the parent activity.

Comment: I am returning to the parent and not starting a new activity - that was the key to moving ahead.  I believe the problem was solved by changing how I implemented the child activity and using `ActivityResultLauncher`.  After coding this things seem to be working!  @ianhanniballake your comment got me going along the ultimately correct path.  If you submit your comment as an answer I will give you credit and close this case.  Thanks so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the parent activity (Activity #1) passes data to the child activity (Activity #2), and then the child activity passes data back to the parent activity.

The important part is that the Activity Result API is only for returning a result - passing a result from your child activity back to your parent activity.

That means that the parent activity is responsible for calling `registerForActivityResult` with the appropriate contract. It would include the information for the child activity as part of the `Intent` that you launch.

Once the child activity is started, it has access to the information passed to it via the Intent extras and it calls `setResult()` to send information back - calling `finish()` to return to the parent activity.

It is only when you return to the parent activity that the `result ->` lambda callback attached to that `registerForActivityResult` callback is triggered, returning the result.

You **do not** override `onActivityResult` at all. You **do not** call `startActivityForResult` at all. The `registerForActivityResult` and calling `launch` on the returned `ActivityResultLauncher` is all you actually need to do on the parent activity side.

Comment: In my case, my call to startActivityForResult(intent, code); did nothing. But I noticed that it was because in the AndroidManifest, i was declaring android:parentActivityName, so the activity i was trying to launch, was ignored because activity name declared in manifest was different.